# Why import "*.css" not working in vite vue3

Tags: leaflet, vuejs3, vite, quasar

I am building vue3 application with vite.
My dependencies

```
 "devDependencies": {
    "@quasar/vite-plugin": "^1.0.4",
    "@types/leaflet": "^1.9.0",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.189",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^2.0.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.2.1",
    "leaflet": "^1.9.3",
    "sass": "1.32.0",
    "typescript": "^4.4.4",
    "vite": "^2.7.2",
    "vue-tsc": "^0.29.8"
  }
```

I made leaflet map on my component but it looks very strange.
I thought that it's style issue, so imported leaflet style but it's not working.

```
import L from "leaflet";
import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";
```

What's the reason?

Comment: This may not be a CSS issue, you can read this https://docs.maptiler.com/leaflet/examples/vite-vanilla-js-default/ on how to use leaflet in Vite

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<div id="map" class="map-wrapper"></div>

<style>
.map-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}
</style>
```

Adding the CSS style to the .map-wrapper class with a width of 100% and a height of 400px ensures that the Leaflet map is displayed correctly within the specified dimensions. The leaflet.css file contains the necessary styles for Leaflet maps, but these styles need to be applied to a container element to properly render the map. By setting the width and height of the .map-wrapper class, you provide the Leaflet map with the dimensions it needs to display correctly.

Comment: Please add some commentary to your post detailing why it resolves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have a component with a setup script. There I import my map.js. In this component I also import the leaflet.css. This works as expected.

Here is an abridged version of the script element of my vue component:

```
<script setup>
    [...]
    import {destruct, init} from '@assets/js/map.js'
    import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';

    [...]
</script>
```

The first line imports the required methods from my map.js, the second imports the leaflet.css. (I also use vite/vue3)